# How to set background image of body after image is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my site, I am using high-res pictures for the background of my body. If I simply put `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('URL OF PICTURE')";`, I can watch the image load vertically down the page. I want to only set the background image once the file has been loaded, and show my default grey background while it is loading. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Image() to load it, listen for `onload` and then add it to the dom when it is loaded.

```
let img = new Image();

img.onload = function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
};

img.src = 'imageUrl.jpg';
```

Comment: I found a very similar solution to this somewhere else. This works great. Thanks!

Comment: How does this work if the image is used as a background on the body?

Comment: @c--misura here's my code

`var img = new Image();
img.onload = function()
{
 document.body.style.backgroundImage = \"url('" . $pics[$rand] . "')\";
}
img.src = \"" . $pics[$rand] . "\";`

I'm using PHP, but the idea is the same.

Comment: @c--misura $('body').css('background-image', 'url( ... )');

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to hide the body, until the page has loaded.

## CSS

`body { opacity : 0 }`

## js

```
 window.addEventListener( "load", function load( e ){ 
     // Remove the load event 
     window.removeEventListener( "load", load, false );
     // Set the body opacity to 1
     document.body.style.opacity = 1;

  }
```